# Replacing label Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, label

Section of my code where it takes a folder in the static directory and shows the contents as label 3. Within the folders under the name will be the movie titles for each series

movie_name = ['terminator', 'fast and furious', 'star wars']

```
    def callback_function(x):
        path = os.path.join('static/',x)
        camel = (os.listdir(path))

        for file in camel:
            label_3 =ttk.Label(self,text = file)
            label_3.grid(sticky="nsew")


    for index, dat in enumerate(movie_name):
        button = ttk.Button(self, text=dat,
                    command=lambda dat=dat: callback_function(dat))
        button.grid(row=index+5, column=0)
        button.grid(sticky="nsew")
        button_dict[dat] = button
```

What I want it to do is replace the current movie titles, not add to the already growing list.
So when you click the terminator button then the star wars button it will show first the terminator movies then replaced with the star wars movies, instead it shows the terminator movies and then adds on with the star wars movies.

Instead of showing

Terminator 1
Terminator 2
etc

then on the next button click of star wars shows

star wars I,
star wars II,
etc

It shows

Terminator 1,
Terminator 2,
etc

and on the next button click

Terminator 1,
Terminator 2,
etc
star wars I,
star wars II,
etc

Comment: You better use `Text` widget instead of `Label`s.  Clear the `Text` widget first before inserting new items into it.

Comment: Consider this approach: [How to get rid of a label ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57943663/7414759)